# How to use two views in one controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to use two views in one controller in codeigniter

```
public function myaccount($user_id) {

    $this->load->model('blog');

    if(isset($_POST['post'])){
    if(strlen($_FILES['inputUpProfile']['name']) > 0) 
    {
    $pic = $this->do_upload('inputUpProfile');

    if ($this->input->post('post') == ''){$type="image";} else {$type="image-with-text";}
    }

    else {$pic = ""; $type = "text"; }

        $result = $this->blog->addPost($user_id, $type  , $this->input->post('post'),$pic);
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    $result = $this->blog->getPost($user_id, 0 , 10);
    $this->template->build("profile" , array("response"=>$result));     
    }
    else{
    $this->template->build('registration_view',$this->data);
    }


    $this->data['user'] = $user;
    $this->data['errors'] = $this->errors;
    $this->template->set_layout('myaccount');
$this->template->build('profile',$this->data);
    $this->template->build('post_profile',$this->data);

    }
}
```

this ic controller function that must open two view, but my problem is open one view.

Comment: Aren't you getting any errors there? You seem to have an extra `}`. You'll see if you indent your code better.

Comment: why dont you call the second view from first view , call firstview and inject second view inside it

Comment: @Fayeq Ali Khan how can inject second view in first view

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$this->data['myaccount'] = $this->template->set_layout('myaccount');
$this->data['profile'] = $this->template->build('profile',$this->data);
$this->template->build('post_profile',$this->data);
```

And you can access the two other views from `myaccount` and `profile`

Or in your view file call the other 2 views like in post_profile page try like

```
$this->template->build('profile',$profile);
```

That $profile will be taken from the controller asigned to the `post_profile` view

Comment: i will try but only open the `post_profile` view only and not open `profile` view

Comment: Then try for the first ans

Comment: i will try this `$this->data['myaccount'] = $this->template->set_layout('myaccount');
$this->data['profile'] = $this->template->build('profile',$this->data);
$this->template->build('post_profile',$this->data);`